# In Pandas df, apply function skiping NaN

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

| Confianza |
| --- |
| 2.0 |
| 4.0 |
| 7.0 |
| NaN |

Expected Output:

| Confianza |
| --- |
| Baja |
| Media |
| Alta |
| NaN |

In a pandas DataFrame, I want to apply this function for a column but skip NaN

```
def condiciones(df5):
    if ( df5['Confianza'] > 4 ):
        return "Alta"
    elif (df5['Confianza'] == 4 ):
        return "Media"
    else:
        return "Baja"


df5['Confianza']= df5.apply(condiciones, axis= 1)
```

The actual problem is I dont want to drop NaN rows, I tried this but returns error when apply
*"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."*

```
elif ( df5['Confianza'] != notnull):
      return NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Confianza": [2.0, 4.0, 7.0, None]})

def condiciones(row):
    if (row["Confianza"] is None) or (np.isnan(row["Confianza"])):
        return np.nan
    elif (row["Confianza"] > 4):
        return "Alta"
    elif (row["Confianza"] == 4):
        return "Media"
    else:
        return "Baja"


df['Confianza']= df.apply(condiciones, axis= 1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it using np.selecgt

```
import numpy as np

df['Confianza']=np.select( [(df['Confianza'].notna() & (df['Confianza']> 4.0)),
                            (df['Confianza'].notna() & (df['Confianza']== 4.0)),
                           (df['Confianza'].notna() & (df['Confianza']< 4.0))],
          ['Alta', 'Media','Baja'],
          df['Confianza'])
df
```

```
Confianza
0   Baja
1   Media
2   Alta
3   NaN
```

Comment: I wanted to keep emptys as emptys , in this code it convert emptys in "Baja" I think you read so fast my question :P, buth thank you! its solved

Comment: Replace default value Baja with df['Confianza'] to keep it s NaN

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when 'axis' is set to 1 then the function applies to each row

> 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.
> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply

So, your mistake is getting the whole series referencing to the dataframe 'df5' in your function.

You can get the same result without utilizing 'apply' actually, but using 'loc'.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc

```
df5.loc[df5["Confianza"] > 4, 'Confianza2']= "Alta"
df5.loc[df5["Confianza"] == 4, 'Confianza2']= "Media"
df5.loc[df5["Confianza"].notna() & (df5["Confianza"] < 4), 'Confianza2']= "Baja"
```

Comment: I dont get well what you refer.. yes I used axis=1 because i want apply the function on each row, I just have to add this line in my function      elif (df5["Confianza"] is None) or (np.isnan(df5["Confianza"])):  return None ... but thank you for your code and point!

Comment: When a function applied to 'axis' 1 or columns then it already has df5 row as its input parameter. So, in https://stackoverflow.com/users/19560513/lowin-li answer you can see 'row' as this parameter. When you invoke "df5["Confianza"]" then you get NOT one row but ALL the rows. So the result of "df5['Confianza'] != notnull" for example is also Series or the result for ALL the rows.

Comment: I guess you are talking about "code etic" or something? "df5" into the function is just I put for visual, I could write "i" "a" "apple" or "row" it works with all hehe but if it is etic, i keep the tip!